# how to see forge logs without entering into server with .ssh

Tags: ssh, laravel-forge

I have laravel forge. I want to see logs. I know where it's located.

`/home/forge/sitename/storage/logs`.

The thing is I don't have **.ssh** access.

All I got is a circle account which means I am part of the team, and I can see servers and other things on `laravel.forge.com`.

How do I see logs without ssh into the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the page `My account` that appears when you click on your name to the top right, you can declare an SSH key.

you can then use the key to access the forge server with the username `forge`.